# gcc compiler for windows of less size

Tags: c, windows, gcc, windows-xp, cygwin

I am using Cygwin with gcc 4.5 to compile a C program. I am using Windows XP. The size of Cygwin package is too large i.e. about to 900MB, and I want a gcc compiler of less size.

1. Is there any gcc compiler of size max 10-15MB to compile C program on windows.
2. Or I can reduce the size of Cygwin package.

Actually there are lot of extra things present in Cygwin package but I don't know which files to remove or keep.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) default installation is much smaller, at around 100Mb.

Comment: I don't know why people continue to use CygWin (a POSIX emulation layer that happens to include a compiler) when all they need is a native compiler...

Comment: @Matteo: if you only want the compiler, Cygwin is overkill; however, if you prefer a *NIX-like development environment (make, bash, grep/ack, git, $scripting_language, ...), the Cygwin package manager is a godsend; this works pretty well even when doing Win32 development thanks to the fact that the distribution includes MinGW cross-compiler packages; in fact, I just updated the Win64 toolchain

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Apart from what 'Christoph' said, cygwin acts like a package manager for all the kinds of apps I want to try or use. With Mingw, I didn't have that convenience.

Comment: @Christoph, yasouser: I never said "CygWin is a useless piece of crap" (actually I use and appreciate it), I said that if what you need is just a C/C++ compiler for Windows there are better alternatives (namely, MinGW, VC++) that will give you a native environment, not depending on cygwin code for the POSIX emulation.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need in cygwin is the gcc package, run the setup.exe and then install select only the "Base" packages and "gcc4" and "gcc4-core" from the "Devel" set. Once you hit the "Next" button it may provide a list of required packages due to dependency. Install all of them and see if it meets your size requirement.